# Using a Slot to Create a Dialog

Tags: c++, qt5, qdialog

I need to create a new window over top of my current program (I'm attempting a dialog in this case) when a button is clicked. I have this working, but I am having trouble editing the content of the Dialog. As far as I'm aware, no .ui file is created for this and it is only being created when I connect the button to the function.

I have tried using a QMessageBox but was unable to resize the window how I needed. And still ran into the issue of adding the other elements.

```
void MyNameSpace::openInfoDialog()
{
    QDialog* Dialog = new QDialog(this);
    Dialog->setWindowTitle("View Stuff");
    Dialog->setMinimumSize(500,250);
    Dialog->adjustSize();
    DialogRunner* msgRunner = new DialogRunner(Dialog, this);
    msgRunner->safeExec();
}
```

This is my connect

```
connect(_Widget.InfoBtn, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(openInfoDialog()));
```

This code does produce a dialog on click, but I need to be able to add things like labels etc to it. I also use QT Designer as my WYSIWYG.

What can I do to create the new window from a button click and have it filled with other text etc ?

Comment: Well you can customize your qdialog class same way you ate your window class or you can create another window class & run it like this mySecondWindow->exec()

Comment: ***As far as I'm aware, no .ui file is created for this and it is only being created when I connect the button to the function.*** There is no .ui file for dialogs created manually in c++ code. However you can create more than 1 widget that has a .ui file in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have this working, but I am having trouble editing the content of
>   the Dialog

You can add ui files in your project:
[image]

Using that option Qt Creator will make a class with cpp and h files and a ui file in which you can add other widgets as you're used to.
use the import directives to use your class where you need it like you did in the code above and you will have your ui file available.
Then connect the clicked signal of your button with the slot of your dialog class. You can do that in the constructor of the class that holds the button.

You can read this approach more in detail in the book [C++ GUI Programming
with Qt 4](http://www-cs.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/cs221/qt/books/C++-GUI-Programming-with-Qt-4-1st-ed.pdf)
on chapter 2 : Creating Dialogs.
It is available for free on the web. It uses Qt4, but in Qt5 it works the same way around.

EDIT: Here is a minimal example that shows you where you can use the needed parts: a mainwindow with a button on it (in the ui file). a Dialog class which also has a ui file (with several widgets on it). When clicking the button on the mainwindow, the dialog form is shown. Thjs is what I asked you for before. It makes it easier to communicate / test.

**pro file**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    dialog1.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    dialog1.h \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    dialog1.ui \
    mainwindow.ui
```

```
**main.cpp**

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

**mainwindow.cpp**
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog1.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Dialog1* dialog = new Dialog1(this);
    connect( ui->pushButton_1, SIGNAL(clicked()), dialog, SLOT(show()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

dialog1.h

```
namespace Ui {
class Dialog1;
}

class Dialog1 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog1(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog1();

private:
    Ui::Dialog1 *ui;
};
#endif // DIALOG1_H
```

**dialog1.cpp**

```
#include "dialog1.h"
#include "ui_dialog1.h"

Dialog1::Dialog1(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent),  ui(new Ui::Dialog1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog1::~Dialog1()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I do not get the same options as I am on Designer not creator and it's also an older version (likely for QT 4)

Comment: Then I advise to follow the link I provided. It is Qt4 (what you want). The writers explain using ui files and also in code, (without ui files.) Did you look into that link?

Comment: Yes I have read the link, I was unable to apply it in a way to get the desired result

Comment: can you make a minimal reproducable example of what you have already?

Comment: The only relevant part of my code missing is where the button is created, but that wouldn't really help. Basically, I need  a  way to make that dialog come up on click and have things like labels, etc

Comment: Do you have a ui file for your dialog?

Comment: ***The only relevant part of my code missing is where the button is created, but that wouldn't really help.*** Your code example does not have a `.ui` so it's difficult to help if you don't create one. And yes you can create as many `.ui` files in designer as you want. I have dozens of `.ui` files in several of my projects.

Comment: Turns out that I had to do an include to tell a python script to generate the files. Thank you for the good information.